# ESP32 bluetooth module does not working properly

Tags: bluetooth, esp32

I want to transfer images over bluetooth using the ESP-32 module. But my esp32 module I coded does not connect to my device even though it is paired. What could be the reason? If you want, I can also send the codes I use as an example. But I don't understand why I'm encountering such an error. This is the first time I've seen a bluetooth module problem that does not connect despite pairing. I would be very grateful if you help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUVF.png)

Edit 1 : First of all, I apologize very much for my mistake because I am new.

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initBT();
  initCamera();
}

void initBT(){
  if(!SerialBT.begin("ESP32CAM-CLASSIC-BT")){
    Serial.println("An error occurred initializing Bluetooth");
    ESP.restart();
  }else{
    Serial.println("Bluetooth initialized");
  }

  SerialBT.register_callback(btCallback);
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth");
}

void btCallback(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param){
  if(event == ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT){
    Serial.println("Client Connected!");
  }else if(event == ESP_SPP_DATA_IND_EVT){
    Serial.println("bağlanmadı");
    Serial.printf("ESP_SPP_DATA_IND_EVT len=%d, handle=%d\n\n", param->data_ind.len, param->data_ind.handle);
    String stringRead = String(*param->data_ind.data);
    int paramInt = stringRead.toInt() - 48;
    Serial.printf("paramInt: %d\n", paramInt);
    setCameraParam(paramInt);
  }
}

void writeSerialBT(camera_fb_t *fb){
  SerialBT.write(fb->buf, fb->len);
  SerialBT.flush();
}

void initCamera(){
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    ESP.restart();
  }

}

void setCameraParam(int paramInt){
  sensor_t *s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  switch(paramInt){
    case 4:
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_UXGA);
    break;

    case 3:
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_SXGA);
    break;

    case 2:
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_XGA);
    break;

    case 1:
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_SVGA);
    break;

    case 0:
    default:
      s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_VGA);
    break;
  }

  capture();
}

void capture(){
  camera_fb_t *fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!fb){
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    return;
  }

  if(fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
    return;
  }

  writeSerialBT(fb);
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: Hi @Atalay Sahan - without seeing the code, for all we know all it does is print that message. Please edit the question to include your code and please copy and paste the text from the image into the question rather than put the info in the image.

Comment: Hi @romkey . I am very sorry for this simple mistake. I have added the code, thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Include the output you get from your Serial. Is `Client Connected!` ever reached? Have you tried calling `SerialBT.register_callback` **before** `SerialBT.begin`?

Comment: Hello @thepirat000. Thank you both for your interest and for your reply. No, as you can see in the screenshot, I only get this output, and I have never tried the solution you suggested, sorry for the late reply.